# Work around Rust string formatter ignoring correct string length for some unicode strings

Tags: rust

I am using println! to line up columns using the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let name_col_w = 24;
    let col_w = 9;

    println!("{:<0name_col_w$}{:<0col_w$}",
    "COL A",
    "COL B",
    name_col_w=name_col_w,
    col_w=col_w,
    
    );
    
    println!("{:<0name_col_w$}{:<0col_w$}",
    "000",
    "OOO",
    name_col_w=name_col_w,
    col_w=col_w,
    );    
    
    println!("{:<0name_col_w$}{:<0col_w$}",
    "麒麟24",
    "OOO",
    name_col_w=name_col_w,
    col_w=col_w,
    );
}
```

This outputs:

```
COL A                   COL B    
000                     OOO      
麒麟24                    OOO
```

Note that the unicode chars are pushing outside of the bounds of the column (second column is not all aligned). However, the length of the string is less that the limit (24).

```rust
extern crate unicode_width;
use unicode_width::UnicodeWidthStr;

println!("{}","麒麟24".len()); // 8
println!("{}","麒麟24".chars().count()); // 4
println!("{}", UnicodeWidthStr::width("麒麟24")); // 6
```

It seems that the Rust format syntax implementation is measuring the width wrong, as the string should be able to fit within the allocated 24 width.

Is there a way to get rust to recognize the correct string width and format it correctly? or am I just doing something fundamentally wrong?

(working example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad28e92a4a94dd22f7064d3fbd6bacf5))

I am using the string format syntax from the [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically there is no incorrect string length here.

The issue is that most monospace fonts don't handle CJK at all, either not supporting it (so falling back to some other front, which is the most likely really) or not being monospaced with respect to CJK: the entire point of a monospace font is that

> [all] letters and characters occupy the same amount of horizontal space

but this is obviously not the case here as your own alignment clearly shows `麒麟` taking more horizontal space than 3 ascii characters:

```
"麒麟",
"OOO",
```

Consequently, while `麒麟24` is 4 characters[0] it occupies the visual space of a bit more than 5, therefore padding to 24[0] throws off the alignment.

I do not think there is any solution aside from using a monospace font complete enough to be monospace over the entire range of characters you expect, or using a GUI toolkit (which would not be affected by this issue). I'm not sure even TUIs / raw terminal output can manage this issue.

In fact this can even be an issue in GUI, because if you really want to get everything just right you need to go through the entire rendering pipeline then measure the actual "bitmap" size (what will actually be displayed on-screen).

In POSIX 2001, `wcwidth(3)` and `wcswidth(3)` are supposed to help querying the terminal to know how wide a character or string will be, this may or may not work depending on the terminal, and only has some odds of working in an actual terminal (e.g. in my actual terminal, 麒麟 takes exactly 4 cells, which obviously is not the case using whatever fontset SO uses).

[0] an other issue you could have is `count` as well as string padding work in terms of *codepoints*, which is already wildly incorrect due to e.g. combining codepoints, this is trivially demonstrable even using just forms which can be encountered in US english:

```
println!("[{:<4}]", "é");
println!("[{:<4}]", "e\u{0301}");
```

outputs

```
[é   ]
[é  ]
```

because the second line uses two codepoints for a single grapheme cluster, which throws off the simplistic computation of alignment (it adds 2 space codepoints to reach 4, except the first two codepoints translate to a single grapheme cluster, therefore we end with 3 grapheme cluster instead of the 4 we were expecting)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. I think the core issue I was makign was conflating char width with the number of characters, which, as you point out, doesn't work if the monospaced font doesnt include all possible unicode chars.

In my case, im not sure what the solution is to line things up in all cases using println! sounds like its not possible in all cases with this approach).

Thank you!